# Map of dropdown buttons, check if id is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering a map of buttons in react to toggle the is-active class. But if i click one of them, all of them are opened. How can i check if only the clicked button toggles the class?
In plain javascript something like this feels much easier. thanks guys!

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

<div
id={"id" + node.id}
key={node.id}
className={`dropdown ${open ? "is-active" : ""}`}
onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
>
```

Comment: is open a propery of the button itself or on the parent? It should be a property of the button itself..

Comment: open is a state of the whole component, which are the buttons inside.. should it probably be a component itself?

Answer (score 1):

Of course all will be active. You need to place an `id` to state in order to check which button is clicked.

```
<div
  className="dropdown"
  id={"id" + node.id}
  key={node.id}
  className={`dropdown ${open === node.id ? "is-active" : ""}`}
  onClick={() => setOpen(node.id)}
>
```

Comment: ok.. it was that easy.. i had no idea how to pass the id.. thank you very much! now i have to figure out how to close it if clicked again! awesome thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can extract your button to component and change it local state when button is clicked.

```
function Button(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div
      className="dropdown"
      id={"id" + node.id}
      key={node.id}
      className={`dropdown ${open ? "is-active" : ""}`}
      onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
    >MyButton</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: tried this too, and even toggling it back works perfectly out of the box with this solution. thanks mate!